# Solve simultaneous equations $2\log(y) = \log(2) + \log(x)$ and $2^y = 4^x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm having trouble finding the solution to the following problem.

(1)  $2\log(y) = \log(2) + \log(x)$

(2)  $2^y = 4^x$

So far all I've managed is:

from (1) simplify using properties of logarithms:

$\log(y^2) = \log(2x)$

$y^2 = 2x$

or from (2)

$2^y = 4^x$

$10^y = \log(y) = 20^x$

neither of which seem to lead to a suitable substitution into the other equation.

tagged as homework as it is obviously homework level, only trouble I don't have a teacher or tutor to ask.

Comment: Your simplification of (2.) is quite wrong. Can you show us how you went from $2^y = 4^{x}$ to $10^y = \log y = 20^x$?

Comment: I figured if I multiplied both sides by 5. $2^y.5 = 4^x.5$ I would have $10^y = 20^x$, then $\log y = 20^x$ as you can see that didn't actually help me

Comment: It didn't help you is one thing. In fact, it is *wrong*. $(2 \cdot 5)^y$ is not $2^y \cdot 5$. It is $2^y \cdot 5^y$. (Also I do not see how you went from $10^y = 20^x$ to $\log y = 20^x$.) You can review the properties of exponentials [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Identities_and_properties).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $2^y = 4^x$, then since $4=2^2$ we have 
$$2^y = 4^x = (2^2)^x = 2^{2x},$$
so $y=2x$.

(Alternatively, taking logarithms you have $y\log(2) = x\log(4) = 2x\log(2)$, so $y=2x$).

So now you know that $y^2=2x$ *and* that $y=2x$. Therefore...

Comment: that's just what i needed, thank you.

Comment: @Gareth By the way, sometimes when we manipulate equations (e.g., eliminate logs by exponentiating), we might end up with what are called "extraneous solutions" (or what you could call "fake solutions"). Remember to always check that each solution is really a solution.

Answer (score 1):

$2^y=2^{2x} \Rightarrow y=2x$, if we plug this into first equation we have $y^2=y \Rightarrow y^2-y=0 \Rightarrow y(y-1)=0$ ,so $y_1=0$ and $y_2=1$ which means that $x_1=0$ and $x_2=\frac{1}{2}$ Since $ln$ isn't defined for $0$ only solution is $(x_2,y_2)=(\frac{1}{2},1)$

Comment: ok so i have a question - where did the y1 and y2 come from at the end? why is there 2 anwsers. I thought you solved simultaniously by taking away y=2x fromy^2=2x ...that gives y=0 and then i get lost ... pls help :)

Answer (score 0):

From equation 
$$y^2 =2x$$
$y=\sqrt{2x}$

Substitute values of $y$ in the equation above.

If you work it smartly, you will find that $y=1, x=0.5$

Comment: Hi, the answers are much more readable if you use `\sqrt{2x}` (this results in $\sqrt{2x}$) instead of 'square root of 2x'. More the other tricks, follow [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/73561).